# How to install MSBuild 15.0 on Windows 2012 (Not R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012, visual-studio, build-server

Can I somehow Install MSBuild 15.0 on Windows 2012 (Not R2)? 
On Windows 2012R2 I installed VSBuildTools2017 and everything is great, but on Windows 2012 (Not R2) server I get an error:

> This Version of Windows is not supported. If you're running Windows 8.0, try upgrading to Windows 8.1.

But in documentation I see the following:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
>   The Build Tools support the same system requirements as Visual Studio with the following changes:
>
> Also installs on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also have this problem. I downloaded the tools from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W2012 is not supported.
The note
"Also installs on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1"
was changed to 
"Also installs on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1"

Answer (score 1):

One way around I find is install (you need know what you will need exactly) it on other computer and then copy it over to this server.
I tested it on Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019.
This mean I copied this whole folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\
```

Nuget.exe can be downloaded separately to refresh all nugests in project.

Basic compilation should work fine but some custom tools could be problematic
(and of course this will be brittle).

In my project I was need to copy OneClick Bootstraper directories too and add registry key that point to that directory.

Better would be upgrading Windows system but as last resort you can do this.